# How to prevent background-image from zooming on mobile browser when adding elements vertically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

I have a ReactJS app in which I add elements vertically from up to down when I press on button "Post".

[image]

When  I add the elements, they are well displayed on mobile and desktop browser.

**BUT**, on the mobile browser, the background image keeps zooming every time I add an element.

[image]

I chose to use Jquery in my `public/index.html` because I need it to change randomly my background image thanks to a function I have (I cannot call a js function inside the `url()` for `background-image` in a CSS file).

I have the following as well for my desktop version and it works, so I know I have to modify my CSS here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  const randomImage = chooseBackground();
  if ($(window).width() < 650) //mobile browser
  {
    $('html, body').css('background-image', `url(${randomImage})`);
    $('html, body').css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
    $('html, body').css('background-attachment', 'fixed');
    $('html, body').css('background-size', 'cover');
    $('html, body').css('background-position', 'center');
  }
});
```

**My objective is to have the background image fixed without moving and zooming on Mobile, and be able to scroll down to see all the elements I added.**

Comment: Hi,
I thinks it's the "background-size: cover" rule who make this behaviors happens. When you add elements the page size change, so the background size too. Have you tried with hard-coded values?

Comment: Yes I tried, but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

`background-size: cover` will use either the vertical or horizontal box limits to fit the image perfectly inside the container. When adding elements, your body grows vertically, which means it'll have to fit the image in a "higher" container than before, thus it looks like zooming.

If you set a `max-height: 100vh` to the body and `overflow: auto`, it should work, see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n0u7z9s2/).

Despite that, you should consider using React for handling the background image as well, since mixing frameworks usually is not a good choice.

**Update**

I tried it on my phone now and it appears this is related to the body scaling anyways on Safari mobile. If you wrap your page in `<div class="wrapper">` or similar and apply the style to this container, it will keep the background image size, since the wrapper's size can be restricted.

Please note, that due to Safari's spring scrolling, this might yield to subpar scrolling experience, see [this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jRxmKz) on your phone.

IMO, the easiest solution would be, to use a `<div class="background">` container, which is `position: fixed` and has a low `z-index`, like in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NmMjQY).

```css
.background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: -1;

  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/300x300);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

This works on my phone (try opening the [result view](https://s.codepen.io/anon/fullpage/NmMjQY) on your phone).

Comment: You tried this on desktop. Sadly, it does not work my mobile app version. For the framework mixing I agree, but there is no way of calling a function from inside your css file in the url property for background-image, that's why I said ``I chose to use Jquery in my public/index.html because I need it to change randomly my background image``

Comment: You're right, I tested on Safari desktop, thinking it'd work the same on Safari mobile... It seems related to the styles being on the body. I updated my answer and used a background container, which works on my phone.

Comment: It is not working, I don't know how to resolve this. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to do with this line `$('html, body').css('background-size', 'cover');`
Try a different value for `background-size`. You can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp).

The value `cover` resizes the background image to cover the entire container, even if it has to ***stretch the image*** or cut a little bit off one of the edges.

Comment: It might also have to do with `background-position` try putting it to other values than `center`. Read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp. Keep in mind to have `background-size` to `auto` instead of `cover` so it doesn't stretch.

Comment: I believe `center` on `background-position` will put the image in the center when the container expands after new elements are added to it. I can't test it out now but together with `background-size` at `cover` it will give a zooming effect. Try putting `background-position` to `center-top` or `left-top` and `background-size` to `auto` or `contain`. Good luck!